# Haskell List of Tuples Compare Pair

Tags: haskell, compare, tuples

I am new to Haskell and I am trying some stuff out. I am having some trouble comparing tuples elements.

Let's say I have a tuple `[(1,3),(2,1),(4,4)]`.
I want to compare each pair index with each other and save some data into a counter value and return that value.

For example what I want is this:
Tuple: `[(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]`
When   `a>b` I want to `add 3` to the counter.
When `a==b` I want to `add 1` to the counter.
Otherwise `add 0` to the counter. Same for `(c,d)` and `(e,f)`.
After iterating through my tuples I want to return the counter.

> So in my example I have tuple `[(1,3),(2,1),(4,4)]`.
>   The function should do
>   Since `1<3` add 0 to counter.
>   Since `2>1` add 3 to counter.
>   Since `4=4` add 1 to counter.
>   And after all return `0+3+1 = 4`.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

(Edit)

```
calculateWins :: [(Int,Int)]->Int           
calculateWins d ((a,b) :xs) = x
    where x 
     |a>b   =   3
     |a==b  =   1
     |otherwise =   0
```

Comment: Being new to something is not really an excuse for lak of effort. Pleace show what you tried, what did not work, what ideas did you had, why these were unsuccesful.

Comment: Furthermore `[(1,3),(2,1),(4,4)]` is *not* a tuple, it is a *list* of 2-tuples.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, you are right. Excuse me for that, indeed that's a list of tuples. I have edited the post adding some code that I wrote but I didn't do that in the first place since I think that it's not something that worths mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the point system of a *soccer cup* (and some other sports). Instead of implementing a function that calculates the sum, we better first aim to calculate something that calculates the score for *one* such tuple, so something like:

```
score :: Ord a => (a, a) -> Int
```

By using `a` as type, we can use any type of values, as long as we can compare them (the `Ord` type constraint). So we can write something like:

```
score (x, y) = -- ...
```

now in case `x > y`, then the score is `3` points, in case `x == y`, then the score is `1` point, and finally in case `x < y` (otherwise), then the score is `0` points, so we can write it as:

```
score :: Ord a => (a, a) -> Int
score (x, y) | x > y = 3
             | x == y = 1
             | otherwise = 0
```

So now we can perform a `map score` to calcuate a list of scores, and by using `sum`, we can calculate the sum of those points, like:

```
calculateWins :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> Int
calculateWins = sum . map score
```

Comment: May I ask you something else too? In my example the list of tuples represents the results from some matches given by a team. In each tuple (a,b) a stands for goals scored by my team and b for goals scored by the opponent team. For example the list of tuples ` [(1,3),(2,1),(4,4)]` represents 3 matches that my team gave. How is it possible to get the biggest difference between goals scored in each match? For example this number should be >0 if my team has at least one win, 0 if no wins and at least one even score and negative if my team has been defited at all matches. Example [(1,5)] I want -4

Comment: For example: [(0,1),(1,3),(1,2)] I want -1. I guess the code is similar to the above one so I hope you are kind enough to help me out.

Comment: Well you can perform another mapping, and then use `maximum` instead of `sum`, a very short implementation is `maximum . map (uncurry (-))`.

Comment: I don't think I was clear about what I want. Let me explain. I have the list of tuples [(8,1),(2,3),(3,3),(2,0)]. My team has 2 wins and 1 even score. I want the difference between the goals of the best match. The best match is the one that the difference between the goals scored is the maximum. In this case 8-1 is the best match, so the return value is 8. However this value depends not only on the scores but at the general results. This value is >0 if my team has at least one win, 0 if no wins and at least one even score (any case), and negative if my team has been defited at all matches.

Comment: @hristoforidisc: precisely, if you define `bestmatch = maximum . map (uncurry (-))`, then you can call it with `bestmatch [(8,1),(2,3),(3,3),(2,0)]`, and this will yield `7`.

Comment: bestmatch ::  Ord a => [(a, a)] -> Int
bestmatch = maximum . map (uncurry (-))    Something like that? I get an error Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : bestmatch
*** Expected type : Ord a => [(a,a)] -> Int
*** Inferred type : Ord Int => [(Int,Int)] -> Int

Comment: @hristoforidisc: the signature is different. For `bestmatch` it is `bestmatch :: (Ord a, Num a) => [(a, a)] -> a`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much mate. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use a function of type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` to transform the list of tuple into a list of your summands (3 or 1 or 0), and use another function of type `[a] -> a` to get the sum.

The [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a very nice site for looking up Haskell functions, both by name and by signature.

Please do try these things out before simply asking for the complete code; that helps neither of us.